# Rolling left join with value fill for all the rows in the left table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have two data.tables (representing rows of the same entity in normalized form), with different number of rows in each table and with updated_at timestamps. I would like to do a rolling left join by matching on the updated_at timestamp so that first dt1 keeps all rows. Only best nearest values from second dt2 should be joined and filled for all rows in dt1.

Examples I have seen and tried create a join where the final table is left with NA for non-matching Windows. But I need all rows in the dt1 to be matched with the nearest record from dt2.

Code I had tried from Stack Overflow references:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)

timestamp <- sort(rnorm(10, mean = 1, sd = 1))

dt1 <- data.table(
  id = letters[1:10],
  timestamp = timestamp,
  timestamp1 = timestamp,
  other1 = 1:10,
  other2 = 11:20
)

dt2 <- data.table(
  timestamp = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  timestamp2 = timestamp[c(3, 5, 8)] + 0.1,
  other3 = c("x", "y", "z"),
  other4 = c(333, 444, 555)
)

dt1[dt2,
    roll = -Inf,
    on = "timestamp", 
    # assign desired values explicitely
    `:=`(dt2_timestamp2 = i.timestamp2,
          other3 = i.other3,
         other4 = i.other4)]
```

Received Output:

```
 id timestamp timestamp1 other1 other2 dt2_timestamp2 other3 other4
    <char>     <num>      <num>  <int>  <int>          <num> <char>  <num>
 1:      a 0.4353018  0.4353018      1     11             NA   <NA>     NA
 2:      b 0.8938755  0.8938755      2     12             NA   <NA>     NA
 3:      c 0.9053410  0.9053410      3     13             NA   <NA>     NA
 4:      d 0.9372859  0.9372859      4     14             NA   <NA>     NA
 5:      e 1.3631284  1.3631284      5     15       1.005341      x    333
 6:      f 1.4042683  1.4042683      6     16             NA   <NA>     NA
 7:      g 1.6328626  1.6328626      7     17       1.463128      y    444
 8:      h 2.3709584  2.3709584      8     18             NA   <NA>     NA
 9:      i 2.5115220  2.5115220      9     19       2.470958      z    555
10:      j 3.0184237  3.0184237     10     20             NA   <NA>     NA
```

Desired output:

```
         id timestamp timestamp1 other1 other2 dt2_timestamp2 other3 other4
    <char>     <num>      <num>  <int>  <int>          <num> <char>  <num>
 1:      a 0.4353018  0.4353018      1     11             NA   <NA>     NA
 2:      b 0.8938755  0.8938755      2     12             NA   <NA>     NA
 3:      c 0.9053410  0.9053410      3     13             NA   <NA>     NA
 4:      d 0.9372859  0.9372859      4     14             NA   <NA>     NA
 5:      e 1.3631284  1.3631284      5     15       1.005341      x    333
 6:      f 1.4042683  1.4042683      6     16       1.005341      x    333
 7:      g 1.6328626  1.6328626      7     17       1.463128      y    444
 8:      h 2.3709584  2.3709584      8     18       1.463128      y    444
 9:      i 2.5115220  2.5115220      9     19       2.470958      z    555
10:      j 3.0184237  3.0184237     10     20       2.470958      z    555
```

Comment: Why do have NAs for ```id %in% c("a", "b", "c")```?

Comment: @M-- I had an error in the code posted. the code for roll should be "roll=-Inf". I have edited the question and the expected output now. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Then `Inf` not `-Inf` (i.e. since the order of the join has switched)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)

setcolorder(dt2[dt1,
                roll = Inf,
                on = "timestamp"], 
            unique(c(names(dt1), names(dt2))))[]

#>     id timestamp timestamp1 other1 other2 timestamp2 other3 other4
#>  1:  a 0.4353018  0.4353018      1     11         NA   <NA>     NA
#>  2:  b 0.8938755  0.8938755      2     12         NA   <NA>     NA
#>  3:  c 0.9053410  0.9053410      3     13         NA   <NA>     NA
#>  4:  d 0.9372859  0.9372859      4     14         NA   <NA>     NA
#>  5:  e 1.3631284  1.3631284      5     15   1.005341      x    333
#>  6:  f 1.4042683  1.4042683      6     16   1.005341      x    333
#>  7:  g 1.6328626  1.6328626      7     17   1.463128      y    444
#>  8:  h 2.3709584  2.3709584      8     18   1.463128      y    444
#>  9:  i 2.5115220  2.5115220      9     19   2.470958      z    555
#> 10:  j 3.0184237  3.0184237     10     20   2.470958      z    555
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `fill` from `tidyr`. It would go after your `roll`

```
library(tidyr)
fill(dt1,names(dt1),.direction='down')
```